# Degenerate local-orbital radial functions

Tags: density-functional-theory

I am trying to do a simple groundstate calculation with the [exciting](http://exciting.wikidot.com/) code for a perovskite structure with *4d*-electron elements. The code uses a muffin-tin approach and expands the wavefunctions inside the muffin tins by augmented plane waves + local orbitals by default.
When running the calculations, above a certain cutoff energy I get the error message:

```
Error(genlofr): degenerate local-orbital radial functions
```

Looking into the source code, it seems like the linear algebra routine `zgesv.f` from LAPACK fails because some factor is singular. I struggle however to understand which parameter in the input I should change to avoid such a problem. Any hint is much appreciated.

EDIT:

The input is a simple ground state calculations with the parameters:

```
<groundstate
  do="fromfile"
  xctype="GGA_PBE"
  rgkmax="8"
  gmaxvr="15"
  ngridk="4 4 4"
  swidth="1d-6"
  epsengy="1d-6"
  maxscl="40">
```

The problematic atoms are Sr and Rh with the pre-compiled species files.

EDIT 2:

After further searches for the root cause, I found a workaround where instead of using a combined local orbital + LAPW basis, I just use LAPW instead. While the code doesn't stop now, the energies become pathological for higher cutoffs. Searching the web, I found that people have similar problems with another all-electron code, ELK ([here and links therein](https://sourceforge.net/p/elk/discussion/897820/thread/0ef1319d/) and [here](http://exciting.wikidot.com/forum/t-615909/convergence-in-rgkmax-difficulties)). It is suggested that high $q$-components of the interstitial effective potential cause instability. Does this warrant a second question or help this one?

Comment: It might help if you include the input in the question.

Comment: I just found that the problem also occurs in a different system with different geometry and atoms, so I suppose that narrows down the most likely cause to the ground state parameters